# Will chat be accessible through the API?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, api, chat

Will chat be accessible through the Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange API?

Comment: This would open the world to cool apps and plugins for existing chat clients... it would be very cool

Comment: If you look at a dump of the traffic going back and forth it looks like an API would be easy. I think the main issue is finding a way to give access to a user's security token and that will probably take some time.

Comment: Yeah, good idea, let's invent *yet* another multi-user chat protocol! </sarcasm>

There exists IRC, XMPP MUC, etc. Pick one; instead of making another HTTP-based "API".

Comment: awesome, I just came looking for this info, and it seems another "carson" is also interested. Woo!

Comment: I was thinking of building a client side app for this, but guess not.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Whatever chat does, it won't be tied to the API proper.

Comment: but why? What if some SO apps could utilize the chat in a meaningful way? I'd hate to see an MSN->SO chat thing, but if the chat is to be an integrated "third place" for all SE sites, I think it should be integrated into the API as well